# Close all buffers in Emacs but preserve neotree open

Tags: emacs

I'm using the [Emacs Neotree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree) plugin that provides a filebrowser sidebar for Emacs, and I have this function to close all buffers but the current one:

```
(defun kill-other-buffers ()
  "Close all other buffers."
  (interactive)
  (mapc 'kill-buffer (delq (current-buffer) (buffer-list))))
```

It works ok, but it closes the neotree navigation too and I want it to remain open. Any idea on how I can get this done?

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/a/896020/206164 -- where it says `(unless (eq ?\s (aref name 0)) . . .` just change it to `(unless (or (eq ?\s (aref name 0)) (equal name (buffer-name (current-buffer))) (equal name "*my favorite buffer*")) . . .)` You probably do not want to kill buffers that have a blank space at the beginning of their names.

Comment: A big +1 for lawlist's final comment. Arbitrarily killing all internal buffers isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since `neo-buffer-name` is defined as `*NeoTree*` in neotreel.el, the following change should do the trick:

```
(mapc 'kill-buffer (delq neo-buffer-name (delq (current-buffer) (buffer-list))))
```